# Python diff between inheriting a class and just passing class instance to another class

Tags: python, inheritance, composition

What is the difference between creating two class one inheriting other and passing first class instance to another class init method ?

Like below,
method 1:

```
class ht(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def ch(self):
        self.filename="hellgmhjkl"


class tt():
    def __init__(self,ob1,ob3):
        self.ob1=ob1
        self.ob3=ob3
        self.b=5

    def display(self):
        print(ob1.filename)
        print(self.ob3.d)

class kk():
    def __init__(self):
        self.c=3

    def hel(self):
        self.d=self.c+5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ob1=ht()
    ob1.ch()
    ob3=kk()
    ob3.hel()
    ob2=tt(ob1,ob3)
    ob2.display()
```

method 2:

```
class ht(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def ch(self):
        self.filename="hellgmhjkl"


class tt(ht):
    def __init__(self,ob1,ob3):
        self.ob1=ob1
        self.ob3=ob3
        self.b=5

    def display(self):
        print(ob1.filename)
        print(self.ob3.d)

class kk():
    def __init__(self):
        self.c=3

    def hel(self):
        self.d=self.c+5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ob1=ht()
    ob1.ch()
    ob3=kk()
    ob3.hel()
    ob2=tt(ob1,ob3)
    ob2.display()
```

What is the diff between method 1 and 2 ?
My requirement is I have several classes : config.py, log.py, analyse.py, HTTPrequest.py, request.py, attack.py

All above classes needs the class variables values from config.py and log.py.
And, analyse.py needs values from request.py and HTTPRequest,py and attack.y needs values from request.py.

Can anybody help me how to inherit like multiple or multilevel or usecomposition or just pass class objects and how?

Answer (score 0):

You inherit from classes when you want to modify behavior of an existing object; as inheritance will give you all the existing properties, methods and behaviors of the parent object; and all you have to do is code your own customization.  Your new object is a derivative of the parent object.

Passing a class means to intend to use the object of that class *as is*, perhaps instantiate a new instance of it.

Remember that classes are just factories for creating custom objects (or types).

If you just need values from a specific file, simply import them:

```
from request import a, b, c
from HTTPRequest import one, two, three
```

Comment: when I import a file with a Class definition its method gets executed automatically before invoking during import process itself. how to import a file with class and methods without getting executed. i cannot enclose my class under if __name__=="__main__": as i couldnt inherit my class name with enclosed main method

Comment: _"when I import a file with a Class definition its method gets executed automatically before invoking during import process itself. how to import a file with class and methods without getting executed."_ - The entire file is evaluated an only if you have a statement like `foo = MyClass()` will the class be instantiated. Otherwise, the code is evaluated but not executed until its needed.

Comment: look at my above answer with screenshots , the code is getting executed twice during import

Answer (score 0):

its working but methods are executed twice always:

```
init.py
```

[image: init.py]

```
HTTPreq.py
```

[image: httpreq.py]

```
anal.py
```

[image: anal.py]

```
tree_structure
```

[image: tree]